# Holomorphic function on several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

A map $f:U\ni(z_1,\dots,z_n)\mapsto f(z_1,\dots,z_n)\in\mathbb C$ (with $U\subseteq\mathbb C^n$ open) is called *holomorphic* if $f$ is real continuously differentiable and for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z_i}}=0$.

**Hartogs' Theorem** now states that $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $f$ is holomorphic with respect to every variable $z_1,\dots,z_n$, see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hartogs_theorem).

I don't see why this is actually a Theorem. Is this not just a reformulation of the definition? Or is it that the definition that I take for holomorphicity is not the one that Hartogs used?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic in each variable it is quite non- trivial to prove that it is continuously differentiable as  a function of $n$ variables.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh, I see the problem now...